# Image loaded 3 times by firefox when using curl & php

Tags: php, firefox, caching, curl

When i'm loading an image by curl through PHP but when opening it in firefox it shows me thet the image is loaded 3 times by checking for caching or something.

I'm using tamper-data and I saw this problem shown below.

[image: Output on Tamper-Data]

I've tried using `header('Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate');` but no solution.

Also by using random get data to force image download and no caching still not working.

Comment: The image is not readable!

Comment: open it in a new tab and it is

Comment: The image is showing in browser @shiplu.mokadd.im as soon as the first ping occurs but the last ping creates problem as the image not changing for the final ping but it changes server variables.

Comment: @Stefan It is already in a new tab

Comment: File sizes are different, what do they correspond to?

Comment: @DoubleGras Actually it is for my captcha system. And as it pings the server 2 times server variable changes but the image only change for the first call of the three.

Comment: You are calling it from clients end. Need to see the code at client side.

Comment: Don't know why this problem arises. But it is solved when I use it on a `<img>` element. It seems that opening the file directly into browser, it thinks as text-stream somehow but it displays as Image and then retrying to load that image again.

When I used the same link as image src it readily thinks it as image and no retrying.

Problem is solved but the cause isn't.